# ResultSet sqlite multi multi columns and multi tables

Tags: java, sqlite

I am beginner on sqlite,I use it I have no choice and I code with java, I have a request that It should return as reslutat two columns, but It returns anything, the resultSet is org.sqlite.RS@..,please I need help on this , thank you in advance.

```
        public List<String> executeSelect( String ArgRequete, boolean All) throws SQLException
{
    String ReturnColumn = ArgRequete.substring( ArgRequete.indexOf( "SELECT" )+ 6, ArgRequete.indexOf( "FROM" ) ).replaceAll(" ","");
    List<String> Str = new ArrayList<String>();
    logger.info("ret :"+ReturnColumn);
    String[] columns=ReturnColumn.split(",");
    for(String ico:columns){
     logger.info(ico);
   }
    stmt = con.createStatement();

    rs = stmt.executeQuery( ArgRequete );
    logger.info(ArgRequete);

    logger.info("mon resultSet:"+rs);
    if ( !All )
    {
        if ( rs.next() )
        {
            String result = "";
                   for(String aColumn : columns){
                                result += rs.getString(aColumn ) + ",";
                                logger.info(result);

                    }
                    Str.add( result );
         }
    }
    while ( rs.next() && All )
    {
                               String result = "";
                               for(String aColumn : columns){
                                           result += rs.getString( aColumn ) + ",";
                               }
        Str.add( result );
    }
    stmt.close();
    return Str;
}

   public void etapeParametrerOption(String login) throws IOException, SQLException
{
    assertTrue( "Texte 'Paramétrer les options' non présent, voir code source HTML dans LogOut",selenium.isTextPresent( "Paramétrer les options" ) );

   String [] tab=LogFile.showWSEtAppelCOffrEFrom(login);
  List<String>ls=new ArrayList<String>();

   for(String itab : tab){

       ls=dbCOffrE.executeSelect("SELECT busitypid,attblabel FROM t_article art, t_attribute att , t_srvbrick_attr_article srv WHERE att.attbid = srv.attbid and art.artid = srv.artid and att.modoptidmodifiable = '2' and (att.attbinactivationdate is null or att.attbinactivationdate < date('now')) and art.artshortlabel='"+itab+"'",false);  logger.info("ma liste :"+ls);
   }}
```

what my file log containt

```
 INFO  [com.sfr.price.functionalTest.commons.SQLBase.executeSelect](82) [] ret :busitypid,attblabel
 INFO  [com.sfr.price.functionalTest.commons.SQLBase.executeSelect](85) [] busitypid
 INFO  [com.sfr.price.functionalTest.commons.SQLBase.executeSelect](85) [] attblabel
 INFO  [com.sfr.price.functionalTest.commons.SQLBase.executeSelect](90) [] SELECT busitypid,attblabel FROM t_article art, t_attribute att , t_srvbrick_attr_article srv WHERE att.attbid = srv.attbid and art.artid = srv.artid and att.modoptidmodifiable = '2'  and art.artshortlabel='8001P'
 INFO  [com.sfr.price.functionalTest.commons.SQLBase.executeSelect](93) [] mon resultSet:org.sqlite.RS@24c672
 INFO  [com.sfr.price.functionalTest.scenario.impl.AJLINGE.etapeParametrerOption](799) [] ma liste :[]
```

Comment: try changing `logger.info("mon resultSet:"+rs);` to `logger.info("mon resultSet:"+rs.toString());` You need to convert it into a String or otherwise human-readable object before spitting it out onto the screen.

Comment: I did this before i changed to rs.toString and always the same resultSet org.sqlite.RS@24c672

Comment: yes i'm using SQLiteJDBC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're getting `org.sqlite.RS@24c672` when printing your result set is because that class has not overridden the default implementation of [toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) in the base object class. According to the [SQLiteJDBC documentation](http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/), you should be able to iterate through the ResultSet and print out values accordingly.

Something like this should work:

```
while (rs.next()) {
    logger.info("busitypid = " + rs.getString("busitypid");
    logger.info("attblabel = " + rs.getString("attblabel");
}
rs.close();
```

Also, I do not understand the purpose of your boolean `All`. (Note: Java style convention indicates that this variable should be named `all`, with lowercase first letter.) Because of the way your `while` loop and `if` statement are written, you will end up either printing *only* the column headings, or *only* the contents of your result set. Based on the contents of your log file, I'd assume you'd passed in `All = false` -- which would make your output correct.

Comment: it doesn't work with this also if iterate the resultSet because when i print my resultSet it shows me this org.sqlite.RS@24c672

Comment: *YES*. This is expected. `logger.info("Resultset = " + rs);` will *always* return "org.sqlite.RS@24c672" or similar because the org.sqlite.RS class does not override the `toString()` method in the Java Object class. You actually need to extract the data from the resultset in order to see the values -- you can't just print the thing directly unless you implement the logic to do just that. [This site](http://www.javabeat.net/2007/08/overriding-the-tostring-method-in-object-class/) might explain it better.

Comment: thank you I now understand why it does not work when i did logger.info("Resultset = " + rs) but even when i iterate my resultSet i always have the same result org.sqlite.RS@24c672